# linking an object from one data service to another data service

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, rest

i have a project i am working on 
the requirements are to build a service to manage customers 
the service has the following functionaltiy

```
Create Customer
Find Customer by Id
Update Customer
Delete Customer
each customer has and id, Name, Email, Address and related credit card tokens
```

When Customer is created it can be linked to one or more credit cards 
and when updating a customer it can be linked to a credit card

The Credit Cards are managed in a different service (one that is not built by me) that i know nothing about (can make some assumptions)

The service i built is a web api project with an sql server database 
i used asp.net entity data model for that and i implemented all of the CRUD operations using the rest api

my question is how can i create the link between the 2 services to allow me to link a credit card from a different service to my customer.

the requirments are that if some one wants to view the data of the credit cards it will need to use the other service so i dont need to have access to the credit card data, only to allow to link a credit card to a customer

any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you asking how to create the credit card tokens? Or you have the credit card tokens and you are asking how to get data from the other service about the credit cards? What do you mean by "the link between the 2 services"?

Comment: i will try to clarify i am asking how to created the credit card tokens for the customer service so i can add them to the customer without knowing much about the service they come from

Comment: What access or functionality do you have for the other service? Can you make calls to the other service? Do they expose any data to you?

Comment: the other service doesnt exist now and when i asked i was told there is now reason to implement it or get its data only to have some link to ti to get tokens (i guess i wont have to actually use it just to show how i would if i needed to ) it is not specified in the instructions otherwise so i can make my own assumptions i think

Comment: that problem is pretty much to use an object that is defined in one web service with another web service without knowing much about the defining web service

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is a little ambiguous and, after reading your comments, it seems your question is essentially asking how to "link" to a different service, which does not exist. If you don't know anything about the other service (and certainly if it does not exist), it will be very difficult to help you "link" to it.

You mentioned that the other service may be developed. In that case, I can suggest the following:

- Connect to the underlying database that the external information is being stored in, much as you are connecting to your own database now (see [connecting to databases in mvc](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-models-and-data-access) for more information)
- If you are not granted access to the external database, you will most likely utilize some form of web service to make queries against the external database (see [consuming web services in mvc](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/653eb2/consuming-web-services-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-application/)).
- From your backend, the logic basically goes: access their database or call their web service, get the id for the credit card and either pass that id through or generate your own (internal) unique id for a credit card (and creata a separate table that stores the original id as well) and associate that with your customer (in an array or object, etc). That way, when you need to retrieve credit card information, you have your customer entry with the information (id(s)) of any associated credit cards. You can use that information to query from the external service to get the required credit cards and then combine the information